# UTF-8 String Capitalization correction in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, utf-8, capitalization, capitalize

I have an application where users enter their names, often in an international format (e.g. Sarah Grüße). I would like to fix the capitalization of users' names when they enter them incorrectly due to laziness, or different international conventions.

Some users do not capitalize their names at all (e.g `mario bel`). When this is the case, I would like to capitalize the first letter of the first and last name (which are different columns in the DB). So the result would be `Mario Bel`.

Some users (often French), capitalize their last names entirely, but this does not fit how we want to display their names. For example `Baptist ALBERT` should become `Baptist Albert`.

Some names correctly have multiple capital letters, thus if a name isn't ALL CAPS or all lowercase, I would like to leave it as is. For example `McDonald` or `von Ramstein`.

Some characters in UTF-8 obviously have no sense of capitalization, thus these names would also stay the same. (Japanese names for example.)

So what I think I need is a way to detect when a name is in all caps or all lowercase, including non-latin case-sensitive characters like `Ü/ü` and ignoring non-latin non-case-sensitive characters like `ß`. Then once detected, correctly change these two cases to First Letter Capitalized.

Comment: What do you do for users who do not have both a first and last name? How about users who have a name like `von Ramstein` or `McDonald` but write it all in lowercase? Capitalizing names correctly in an international context is quite hard; your proposed algorithm would handle a few cases properly, but turn `bill mcdonald` into `Bill Mcdonald`, which is not particularly better. Any good reason not to just let users enter names as they wish and just preserve that?

Comment: First and last names are separate fields and are both required fields in the form. Thus whatever solution will be applied to both of these fields. There are many users that enter their names incorrectly and then are disappointed when our published documents have their names uncaptialized. While `Mcdonald` may not be better than `mcdonald` I certainly don't think it is worse.